# XStream returns attribute value as null

Tags: java, xstream

Today I faced strange behavior of XStream. So, XML:

```
<AddressObjectType KOD_T_ST="0" LEVEL="0" SOCRNAME="blabla"/>
```

Java class:

```
@XStreamAlias("AddressObjectType")
public class AddressObjectType {

    @XStreamAsAttribute
    @XStreamAlias("KOD_T_ST")
    private Integer id;

    @XStreamAsAttribute
    @XStreamAlias("SOCRNAME")
    private String name;

    @XStreamAsAttribute
    @XStreamAlias("SCNAME")
    private String shortName;

    @XStreamAsAttribute
    @XStreamAlias("LEVEL")
    private int level;
    // . . . getters, setters
}
```

I have problem with only attribute `KOD_T_ST`. During deserialization always throws `com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException` and cause is `NullPointerException`. Attribute value is always `null`. Even I switch type from `Integer` to `String`.
What is going on? Does XStream has any limitations for alias names? How to read value?

XStream version 1.4.11.1.

Many thanks for your help and best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your existing xml string

```
<AddressObjectType KOD_T_ST="0" LEVEL="0" SOCRNAME="blabla"/>
```

Instead of using the above, use the below one, it will work, there is no change in the AddressObjectType object model. Mark the difference, there is double underscore(__) in the xml which I provided.

```
<AddressObjectType KOD__T__ST="0" LEVEL="0" SOCRNAME="blabla"/>
```

To understand, refer below the link.
http://x-stream.github.io/faq.html#XML_double_underscores

To quote,

> Why do field names suddenly have double underscores in the generated
>   XML? XStream maps Java class names and field names to XML tags or
>   attributes. Unfortunately this mapping cannot be 1:1, since some
>   characters used for identifiers in Java are invalid in XML names.
>   Therefore XStream uses an XmlFriendlyNameCoder to replace these
>   characters with a replacement. By default this NameCoder uses an
>   underscore as escape character and has therefore to escape the
>   underscore itself also. You may provide a different configured
>   instance of the XmlFriendlyNameCoder or a complete different
>   implementation like the NoNameCoder to prevent name coding at all.
>   However it is your responsibility then to ensure, that the resulting
>   names are valid for XML.

Comment: But `LEVEL` successfully converts to Integer. Moreother, making `id` as String will always getting null as value.

Comment: I have updated the answer, could you please check now ?

Comment: It doesn't work. I even wrote My own converter! But in converter I have `null` as string value.

Comment: Let me check now.

Comment: I have updated the answer, hope it is useful to you.

Comment: Yes. After debug I found it too. Thanks for the answer.